# What kind of values we can add to List<B> type?

Tags: java, generics

```
Class A{
    public static void main(String args[])
    List<B> list=new ArrayList<B>();
    list.add("what type of value should we add here");
}

Class B{
    int a;
    boolean b;
    String c;
}
```

Comment: To a `List<B>`, you can only add objects of type `B`.

Comment: Your code example does not show that you did not even compile your example. Can you please review it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add:

- references of type `B`
- references of any class which is a subclass of `B`
- `null`

However, if you get a reference out of the list, its compile-time type will always be of type `B` -- even if the runtime type is actually a subclass, or `null`.

Answer (score 1):

you can add  objects of type `B` only

```
Class B{

    int a;
    boolean b;
    String c;

    public B(int a , boolean b , String C){

        this.a =a;
        this.b =b;
        this.c =c;
    }
}

B Badd = new B(2,true,"ADD");
list.add(Badd);
```

Comment: You can also add subclasses of B (though they'll be typed as just `B` when you extract them).

Comment: @yshavit yes we can !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can only add Object of B or Object of its child class in other word Object which satisfy obj instantof B can be added